# css, center double digit <li>

Tags: html, css

I have

```
<ul id="list">
  <li> 
     <a href=''>1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href=''>2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href=''>3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href=''>4</a>
  </li>
  ...
  <li>
      <a href=''>10</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href=''>11</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And with style looks like:

[image]

I wish to have double digit numers centred like single digits are. I've tried (separately):

```
#list li{
  text-align: center;
  align-items: stretch; // and center
  margin-left: auto; //with margin right the same
  left: 0;
}
```

But nothing seem's to do the trick

Comment: if you have a width on your 'a' tags with text-align center then that should do it (might need to add display inline-block to the 'a' tag depending on any other css effecting it

Comment: It's working: http://jsfiddle.net/wpqqowfe/

Comment: Can't say for sure without a full example that replicates the issue but it's most likely `padding-left` that pushes the numbers right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set text-align to a:

```
#list li a{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: would seem I have some issue with a width attribute, all fixed now. cheers